Python. вычисление расстояние между двумя городами
на входе программа принимает координаты двух городов, необходимо вычислить расстояние между ними по дорогам (не по прямой). Пытался использовать библиотеку GeoPy (Nominatim и geodesic), но, то ли он вычисляет напрямую, то ли слишком большая погрешность. Как реализовать данную функцию?
P.S. платные варианты не подходят

Предполагаю, что вопрос немного не по теме сайта. здесь помогают с решением конкретных проблем.
